# Excel VBA: Highlight/change colour of certain cells depending on value of dropdown list (not conditional formatting)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I’m looking to create a form with some dropdown options in cells L10 and L12. Depending on the value of those cells I’m then looking to highlight certain cells to help the user know which fields are mandatory to be filled then after. This will be for Excel 2003 so I cannot use conditional formatting due to only being able to have 3 therefor it needs to be in VBA.

I’m at a stumbling block and probably overthinking this but can anyone help me please?

Requirements below:

```
If L10 = yes
Then L12 = yellow

If L12 = yes OR no OR maybe
Then L16, L18, L20, L24, L26 = yellow

If L12 = progress
Then L14, L16, L18, L20, L24, L26 = yellow

If L12 = fail
Then L16, L18 = yellow

If L12 = assess
Then L14, L16, L18, L20, L24, L26 = yellow

If L10 = no
Then L16, L18, L20, L24, L26 = yellow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA editor, select your worksheet and in `Worksheet_Change` sub, add the below code (screen print attached as an example. Also make sure you select the sheet you are working with):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("L10,L12"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        SetCellColour Target
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Now in your `Module`, add the following sub:

```
Sub SetCellColour(ByVal oTarget As Range)
    Dim oW As Worksheet: Set oW = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8")     ' Change the sheet name

    Select Case oTarget.Address
        Case "$L$10"
            Select Case LCase(Trim(oTarget.Value))
                Case "yes"
                    oW.Range("L12").Interior.Color = 65535
                Case Is = "no"
                    oW.Range("L16, L18, L20, L24, L26").Interior.Color = 65535
            End Select
        Case "$L$12"
            Select Case LCase(Trim(oTarget.Value))
                Case "yes", "no", "maybe"
                    oW.Range("L16, L18, L20, L24, L26").Interior.Color = 65535
                Case "progress", "assess"
                    oW.Range("L14, L16, L18, L20, L24, L26").Interior.Color = 65535
                Case "fail"
                    oW.Range("L16, L18").Interior.Color = 65535
            End Select
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect buddy. Cant thank you enough for this!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped